# How to call and consume stored procedure from within another stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table variable and the logic to populate this table is complex enough to where I need to include it in a separate stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @UserExtendedSecurity TABLE
(
    UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    UserName VARCHAR(500),
    HasExtendedSecurity BIT     
)
```

So let's say that I encapsulate this logic in another stored procedure named `GetUserExtendedSecurityData` which returns a result with columns that map to the `@UserExtendedSecurity` table variable above.

Let's say that my main stored procedure is named `GetUsers` and that's where my primary `@UserExtendedSecurity` table variable is defined.

How could I call `GetUserExtendedSecurityData` from `GetUsers` and populate the result into my primary `@UserExtendedSecurity` table?

Comment: Have a look here too: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a normal `INSERT INTO`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetUsers 
AS 
BEGIN

/* some code */

DECLARE @UserExtendedSecurity TABLE
(
    UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    UserName VARCHAR(500),
    HasExtendedSecurity BIT     
);

INSERT INTO @UserExtendedSecurity
EXEC GetUserExtendedSecurityData;

/* some more code */

END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO @UserExtendedSecurityTable (UserName, HasExtendedSecurity)
EXEC GetUsers ...
```

GetUsers returns no results on its own, so the results from GetuserExtendedSercurityData get populated.